# What is the purpose of different version of class file in "target/classes" folder when i do maven-build?

Tags: maven

There is a java file named "CustomerDao.java" in my project.
When i build my java project using maven . So in the folder "target\classes(structure of my project)", "CustomerDao$2.class",CustomerDao$1.class,CustomerDao$3.class,CustomerDao$4.class.... upto 35 , class files have created .

So what this number stands for & what is the purpose of these files .
Why every time different versions of files are getting appeared ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have nothing to do with Maven, and they are not different version of files.

They are simply anonymous inner class.  Although in code, there is no name for the anonymous inner class, Java compiler is going to create a corresponding class (and hence, a class file)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply .
But i have a doubt , I am not using any inner class in my code .
So which inner class u are talking about ?
I have used ojects of different classes, So you are talking about that or any other ?

Comment: something like this : `new SomeInterface(){ void someMethod(){ //yourimpl;}}`